# Applescript to reboot router by clicking on buttons

Tags: network, applescript, router

I am attempting to write an applescript to reboot a router using Safari during the night when no one is using the network.  I can successfully log into the router but am having trouble in selecting the button.  It appears that the button is in a frame and I don't know how to select the button in the frame.  After logging in, the HTML code appears as:

```
<frame name="topFrame" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="./frame/top.htm" noResize scrolling="no" frameSpacing="0" frameBorder="0">
    <frameset cols="182,55%,*">
        <frame id="frame1" name="bottomLeftFrame" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="./MenuRpm.htm" noResize frameBorder="1" scrolling="auto" style="overflow-x:hidden">
        <frame id="frame2" name="mainFrame" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="./mainFrame.htm" frameBorder="1">
        <frame name="helpFrame" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="./help/StatusHelpRpm.htm" frameBorder="1">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Inside the code for the "bottomLeftFrame," I want to click on the button below:

```
<li class="ml1"><a href="#__time.htm" id="menu_tools" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T  plus">System Tools</a><ul class="mu2  nd"><li class="ml2"><a href="#__time.htm" id="menu_time" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T ">- Time Settings</a>        </li><li class="ml2"><a href="#__pingNTraceRoute.htm" id="menu_diag" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T">- Diagnostic</a></li><li class="ml2"><a href="#__defaultCfg.htm" id="menu_def" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T">- Factory Defaults</a></li><li class="ml2"><a href="#__restart.htm" id="menu_restart" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T">- Reboot</a></li><li class="ml2"><a href="#__password.htm" id="menu_mcl" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T">- Password</a></li><li class="ml2"><a href="#__log.htm" id="menu_log" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T">- System Log</a></li><li class="ml2"><a href="#__stat.htm" id="menu_stat" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T">- Statistics</a></li></ul></li>
```

Can someone please show me how I can select the menu item with the id of "menu_tools"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for me to know if this following code will help you, without being able to see the website and test the script.  The action for clicking a button in Safari (by identifying the button by its ID), requires the use of JavaScript within your AppleScript code…

As long as this button is not within a drop-down menu or pop-up window or something else, this script should work for you

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('menu_tools').click();" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: To get this solution to work you need to activate JavaScript from Apple Events in Safari.
To achieve this manually, one would do the following:
Launch Safari, go Preferences>Advanced and check Show Develop menu in the menu bar.
From the menu bar, go to Developer and check the Allow JavaScript from Apple Events.
Authenticate with administrative credentials.

Comment: I neglected to mention above that I enabled Allow JavaScript from Apple Events.